# How to resolve Code Analysis - CA1720 for GUID datatype

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, code-analysis

CA1720 for datatype GUID, Warning shown as follows:

> > CA1720    Identifiers should not contain type names   In member 'ABCService.GetReport(Guid)', consider replacing the data type identifier 'GUID' in parameter name 'reportGUID' with a more generic term, such as 'value'.

How to handle GUID datatype?

Comment: The rule explains it clearly... just remove the GUID from the parameter name

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531486.aspx)

> **If fired against a parameter:**
> Replace the data type identifier in the name of the parameter with either a term that better describes its
> meaning or a more generic term, such as 'value'.
>
> **If fired against a member:**
> Replace the language-specific data type identifier in the name of the member with a term that better describes
> its meaning, a language-independent equivalent, or a more generic
> term, such as 'value'.

Simply use a classic Id, Uid, UniqueIdentifier, ... and not Guid.

Suppress the rule if you think it's important or  if the library have been previous shipped

```
[SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Naming", "CA1720:IdentifiersShouldNotContainTypeNames")]
```

Comment: Any thoughts on why the code analysis engine behave this way? I mean it's reasonable to me not to have a data-type as a part of the name but what is the motivation behind this? any performance concerns?

Comment: @RamiShareef: It has nothing to do with performance. It just helps developers to avoid antiquated patterns that make code harder to read. It's easy for some developers to fall into the trap of using a type *instead* of a more descriptive name (e.g. `personStr` instead of `personSummary` or `personName`). When we're forced to find some other way to disambiguate variable names, we tend to come up with more meaningful names.

Answer (score 1):

`reportGUID` contains `guid` in its name. The rule says you should remove it from the name of the parameter.

Do provide a name that is related to the meaning of the parameter, not its type. One solution would be `reportID`.

Answer (score 0):

Add [NoWarn] on the *.csproj file to disable it.

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <NoWarn>$(NoWarn);CA1720</NoWarn>
    .....
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Answer (score 0):

While this rule is useful in general, it generates noise for enum member names. Consider the following enum:

```
enum SelectionMode
{
    Single,
    Multiple
}
```

The analyzer warns for the `Single` enum item since its name is the same as the .NET type `System.Single`.

It is not uncommon for enum fields to have .NET type names (.NET itself or other libraries already have enum items violating this rule) and I think the rule can be treated as noise for enum items. So I don't see any problem in suppressing it.